# Magento Homepage blank space under main slider

Tags: magento

I cant find any related solution to my problem here on stack over flow but here we go. i have checked footer space and marked related module with zero spacing for slide but still it is not working.
Please see www.sateeni.com and under main homepage slider i have some unwanted space and don't know why its there. Please need help to find out why and where the problem is. sorry if its very basic thing but i am new to magento so cant figure out the reason. I have tried all options but no luck. 
Thanks in advance. 
Adam

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Is this a css issue? Can you provide some code examples of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main content container is showing and even though it is empty, the CSS has padding and a minimum height:

```
 .main {
     padding: 20px 0;
     min-height: 370px;
 }
```

You can either use CSS to overwrite this min-height on the homepage only

```
 .container.full-width {
     padding: 0;
     min-height: 0;
 }
```

or just hide this element on the homepage only.

```
.container.full-width {
     display: none;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. before i go for your above suggested option, here i would like to tell you that i cant save my custom home page under CMS > Pages > home_page> so what i do i just put a "." over there to save the page. any suggestions on this?

Comment: Presumably your homepage is directly calling a template file, but you can't save without leaving it blank. Please accept if your CSS answer is resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used second option display: none; but now on other screens where i have empty pages footer is gone up to the header. please take a look at http://www.sateeni.com/accessories.html wondering how we can just edit the homepage only or is there any other fix for this.... once again thanks for your consideration towards solution. Best from Adam

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know your template. Easiest solution is to add a class to the homepage template then specify that with the display:none so that it only applies on the homepage.